PDF file cannot be opened, when generated with Django and WeasyPrint
I recently began trying generating PDF reports with Django and Weasyprint, but I cannot make it work somehow.
I already have file upload, file download (even PDFs, but already generated ones that were uploaded), CSV generation and download, XLSX generation and download in my application, but I'm not able to return PDFs generated with WeasyPrint so far.
I want my users to be able to create reports, and they'll be saved for further new download.
So I created this basic model :
from django.db import models

class HelpdeskReport(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = "helpdesk"
        db_table = "helpdesk_report"
        verbose_name = "Helpdesk Report"
        verbose_name_plural = "Helpdesk Reports"
        default_permissions = ["view", "add", "delete"]
        permissions = [
            ("download_helpdeskreport", "Can download Heldpesk Report"),
        ]

    def _report_path(instance, filename) -> str:
        return f"helpdesk/reports/{instance.id}"

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=_report_path)

Since I use service classes, I also did :
import uuid
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files import File
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from weasyprint import HTML

class HeldpeskReportService:
    def create_report(self) -> HelpdeskReport:
        report_name = f"helpdesk_report_{uuid.uuid4().hex}.pdf"
        html_source = render_to_string(template_name="reports/global_report.html")
        html_report = HTML(string=html_source)
        pdf_report = html_report.write_pdf()
        # print("check : ", pdf_report[:5])  # It gives proper content beginning (PDF header)
        pdf_bytes = BytesIO(pdf_report)
        pdf_file = File(file=pdf_file, name=report_name)
        report = HelpdeskReport(name=report_name, file=pdf_file)
        report.full_clean()
        report.save()
        return report

Note that for testing purpose, the template is very (too?) basic :
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <article>
    <h2>test report</h2>
  </article>
</body>
</html>

Then the view to call this is as follow (I removed auth classes and so on on purpose to simplify code here, as well as intermediary layer that normally instantiate service classes) :
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.request import Request

@api_view(http_method_names=["POST"])
def create_report(request: Request) -> HttpResponse:
    """
    Create a HelpdeskReport.
    """
    report = HelpdeskReportService().create_report()
    response = HttpResponse(content=report.file)
    response["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={report.name}"
    return response

It does download the file, but once I try to OPEN it in Google Chrome, it does the following, with no other kind of error whatsoever (even in my backend django container) :

Speaking of backend django container, my development backend container Dockerfile contains this :
FROM python:3.12.7
...
RUN apt-get install -y weasyprint
...
RUN pip install -r requirements/development.txt

Note that in my development.txt I also have weasyprint==63.0.
I have no error saying that I have a missing weasyprint dependency.
If some information is missing, tell me and I'll add it.
If someone has already had the problem, I would be grateful to have some help.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT :
I tried to use qpdf as @AKX suggested, here is the result :
qpdf helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf -
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf: file is damaged
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (offset 2612): xref not found
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf: Attempting to reconstruct cross-reference table
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 6 0, offset 196): expected endstream
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 6 0, offset 66): attempting to recover stream length
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 6 0, offset 66): recovered stream length: 224
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 10 0, offset 1560): expected endstream
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 10 0, offset 373): attempting to recover stream length
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 10 0, offset 373): recovered stream length: 2194
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 11 0, offset 2894): expected endstream
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 11 0, offset 2636): attempting to recover stream length
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 11 0, offset 2636): recovered stream length: 455
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 16 0, offset 3889): expected endstream
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 16 0, offset 3187): attempting to recover stream length
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 16 0, offset 3187): recovered stream length: 1248
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 17 0, offset 4628): expected endstream
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 17 0, offset 4567): attempting to recover stream length
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (object 17 0, offset 4567): recovered stream length: 96
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (xref stream: object 17 0, offset 4628): expected endstream
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (xref stream: object 17 0, offset 4567): attempting to recover stream length
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (xref stream: object 17 0, offset 4567): recovered stream length: 96
WARNING: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf (offset 4567): error decoding stream data for object 17 0: stream inflate: inflate: data: incorrect header check
qpdf: helpdesk_report_414b3290fe6b4aae83293694cfa64c25.pdf: error decoding candidate xref stream while recovering damaged file


I assume that the downloaded file is very small and as content (if you open it in a text editor, it only shows the path of the file)?

@willeM_VanOnsem According to my file explorer (in Ubuntu), the file is 8.5kB and its content starts with %PDF-1.7 then unreadable stuff, then <</Filter /FlateDecode/Length 130>> stream then unreadable stuff, then lots of byte like things (\00\00\0A......) then unreadable stuff again, then endstream endobj startxref 2611 %%EOF

Can you see if other tools like qpdf find anything wrong with the file?

@AKX I'll try to check it now.

@AKX You can see the result in the original post. Also I have to mention that I tried adding every listed dependency explicitely but no effect. Even on the simplest template.

There must be an issue with the way I install WeasyPrint or the way I generate the PDF but I can't figure out what is the problem.

That looks like weasyprint is somehow outputting an invalid PDF. Can you try a different version of weasyprint, e.g. weasyprint~=62.0?

Also, maybe print(f"{len(pdf_report)=}"), just so can be sure the data you download is the same length as what weasyprint had output.

@AKX I'll try both today.

@AKX Ok I made some progress. The generated file is OK locally, but when I send it alongside the response, this one is corrupted. So it has to do with the way I return it in the response. Even without using django file field, just write_pdf, then put that result in a BytesIO, then content=pdf_bytes.read() in the response, it doesn't work.

Try report.file.seek(0) before creating the response..?

@AKX Yeah I already tried that but ... not working either :-/ Here since the file is saved and is OK when I open it manually from my file server, I open it with open(report.file.path, "rb") as pdf_file then response = HttpResponse(content=pdf_file.read()) but not working either.

@AKX Ok i found... I'll post an answer with my findings.

From the beginning I made the assomptions that :

The generated PDF file was the issue
Once I fixed that (or figured out it wasn't), I thought it was my way of returning it (which was strange since I already do something similar elsewhere in my code).

So I took the problem the other way and went to my frontend (a bit late to be honest) and I realized I forgot to put the responseType as blob ... :facepalm:
BUT, after figuring out this, another problem was still there. To create my report (and return it alongside the response), I used an AXIOS POST request, which doesn't seem to work with { responseType: 'blob' }. And I didn't know about it.
So I have 2 options :

Make a GET request to create and download my PDF report in a single query.
Make a POST request to create it and return the 'id' of the report, then a GET request to download it.

If anyone knows why I'm not able to make it work with a POST request, I'd be glad to learn.
Anyway, the result is this :
def create_report(self) -> HelpdeskReport:
    report_name = f"helpdesk_report_{uuid.uuid4()}.pdf"
    html_source = render_to_string(template_name="reports/global_report.html")
    pdf_report = HTML(string=html_source).write_pdf()
    pdf_bytes = BytesIO(pdf_report)
    pdf_file = File(file=pdf_bytes, name=report_name)
    report = HelpdeskReport(name=report_name, file=pdf_file)
    report.full_clean()
    report.save()
    return report

@api_view(http_method_names=["GET"])
@authentication_classes([...])
@permission_classes([...])
def create_report(request: Request) -> HttpResponse:
    # Simplified version here :
    report = HelpdeskReportService().create_report()
    response = HttpResponse(content=report.file)
    response["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={report.name}"
    return response

Frontend is Vue.js v2 :
methods: {
  async createReport () {
    this.loadingCreation = true
    const response = await HelpdeskReportingService.createReport()
    FileService.downloadFile(response)
    this.loadingCreation = false
  },
}

where createReport is :
static createReport = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await http.get('helpdesk/reports/create', { responseType: 'blob' })
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    handleAxiosError(error)
  }
}

AKX wrote

...you can use createObjectURL and create an ` element and simulate a click on it for the same effect.

and it's exactly what I do in my FileService :
static downloadFile (httpResponse) {
  const filename = this.getFilename(httpResponse)
  const file = httpResponse.data
  const blob = new Blob([file], { type: file.type })
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  link.download = filename
  link.click()
  URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)
}

Hope it might help some people.

Can you show the relevant frontend code?

As for the aside: You can use an invisible <form> to POST your data, and have the browser download the result as usual since the response's disposition is attachment. Or, if you don't want to do that and want to use fetch() or similar, you can use createObjectURL and create an <a href="blob:..." download="...">` element and simulate a click on it for the same effect.

@AKX yes it's what I'm used to, I added FE code for those who need it.

Well, there's no reason why responseType: blob shouldn't work with POST requests, other than some Axios quirk or bug. It should work fine with fetch, anyway.

I agree with that but :shrug:

report.file will be a FieldFile [Django-doc] (not to be confused with a FileField model field [Django-doc]), so if you use this as content, it will call str(..) on it, and thus write the name of the filepath.
You can open the file, and thus dump the content in the response:
@api_view(http_method_names=['POST'])
def create_report(request: Request) -> HttpResponse:
    report = HelpdeskReportService().create_report()
    with report.file.open(mode='rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(content=fh.read())
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f"attachment; filename={report.name}"
    return response
But this is not a good idea: Django is not good with serving files. Typically you use a webserver like nginx for that, which has advanced streaming and caching mechanisms.
You can let the webserver like nginx serve the file, by returning a response with an X-Accel-Redirect header:
@api_view(http_method_names=['POST'])
def create_report(request: Request) -> HttpResponse:
    report = HelpdeskReportService().create_report()
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = f'/protected/{report.file.path}'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f"attachment; filename={report.name}"
    return response
and then let Nginx handle the file itself with:
location /protected/ {
  internal;
  alias   /path/to/directory/where/you/store/pdf/files/;
}


TBH, I think the X-Accel-Redirect stuff here is a bit extraneous (especially since that won't work with runserver anyway...)

@AKX: well not with runserver, but using Django's runserver as main webserver is a horrible idea, and makes webserver completely unscalable. The main reason not to let Django handle the files is because if these are large, it blows up memory, and if you stream it, it results in the protocol going through the proxy which is not ideal either, and also has not much caching.

I do that kind of thing in my production environment (nginx, redirect,..) for instance with User pictures. But not for file download. And indeed during develoment I use runserver so this won't work.

Sure. I like uwsgi or gunicorn + whitenoise in production. But having a solution that won't actually serve your file while you're trying to develop it is a bit annoying.

@AKX: well, I worked with a helper function that in development serves the file, and in production accts with X-Accel-Redirect.

Well, if OP's file is about 8 kilobytes, there's no need to use any transfer acceleration. And in any case, as visible from their comment in the original post, their code does manage to download something that looks like a PDF, not a filename.

@AKX: no, but I always assume that you don't per se have control over the file size. This can be a rendered table with records, if there are a billion records, the file grows. A friend of mine once received a file with more than 300'000 pages from the university :P

@willeM_VanOnsem I can already upload a PDF document as a TicketAttachment and download it again without any problem. I think here the problem comes from the generation itself. And for downloading files, I don't even need a file handler context. Just doing HttpResposne(attachment.file) (for my ticket attachments with a FileField too) works.

There must be an issue with the way I install WeasyPrint or the way I generate the PDF but I can't figure out what is the problem.
